# Replace words in a column with different text

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I have been trying to do this for quite some time.

I have an excel sheet has text In-today and "Starting" as well as other text that is meant to be there.  How do I create a formula that replaces the words In-Today and first word "Starting" in Column A with word "N/A"

SUBSTITUTE(A2,"In-Today","N/A") works but what about "Starting".

```
Col A
In-Today
Starting by the side of the ridge
Starting at 14:00
In-Today
Starting 15:00
Starting adwada14
```

Thanks

Comment: Substituteception https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313965/how-can-i-combine-multiple-nested-substitute-functions-in-excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"In-Today","N/A"),"Starting","N/A")
```